# How to filter out '.svn' files during the checkout process?

Tags: svn, filter, svn-checkout

Subversion checkouts produce a large number of files under the '.svn' trees.
Is there any way to filter out '.svn' files during the checkout process?

Thanks,
Sen

Comment: .svn files are part of subversion itself.  You cannot filter them out, else subversion would stop working.

Comment: you need these files if you'd like to be able to commit your changes. Otherwise do an export.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

See `svn export`. It should help.

- http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.0/re10.html

The first form exports a clean directory tree from the repository specified by URL, at revision REV if it is given, otherwise at HEAD, into PATH. If PATH is omitted, the last component of the URL is used for the local directory name.

As yodaj007 says, this will extract all the files from a revision and the directory will not be a revision controlled one. To obtain revision controlled directory, you use the usual `svn co`.

Comment: i am checking out form a http:// path and i gave the following command : __svn export https://<myIP>/svn/<myProjectName>/tags/AS011049/ AS011049/__. Does it not display anything on the screen?

Comment: I dint understand.. you mean a "DOT".

Comment: @Sen: You exported the tag AS011049 into a folder called AS011049 that is located in the directory where you executed the export. What did you expect to happen on the screen?

Answer (score 2):

I know this is a late post, but if you don't want the .svn files stored in your directory because you want to zip it up or hand it off to someone else void of those files, please use this perl script to remove the .svn files. Note by using this you would not be able to use svn commit to commit back to the repository since you delete the .svn files.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use File::Path;
use strict;

# Only run program on valid input MAX/MIN_INPUT = 1
if ( @ARGV == 1 ) {
    my $file = $ARGV[0];
    #Do some regular expression verrification
    &dot_svn_del_func ( $ARGV[0] );
} else {
    die "ERROR: to many arguments passed";
}

sub dot_svn_del_func {
    my $path = shift;
    opendir (DIR, $path) or die "Unable to open $path: $!";
        my @files = grep { !/^\.{1,2}$/ } readdir (DIR);
        closedir (DIR);
        @files = map { $path . '/' . $_ } @files;
        for (@files) {
            if (-d $_) {
            my $svn_found = 0;
            my $path = $_;
            my @path_components = split(/\//,$path);
            my $path_count = 0;
            foreach my $new_path (@path_components) {
                if ( $new_path eq ".svn" ) {
                    rmtree($_,1,1);
                    $svn_found = 1;
                }   
                $path_count++;
            }
            if ( $svn_found == 0 ) {
                #print "Making recursive calls from ".$_."\n";
                        &dot_svn_del_func ( $_ );
            }
        }
   }
```

}